# Vim regex: Match lines with different start than next line

Tags: regex, vim

I want to match lines that are followed by a line starting with a different number, as the third line does in this example.

```
1 foo
1 bar
1 foobar
2 Foo
2 Bar
```

1. What is the best regex for this?
2. Why do the following two attempts fail?
   `\v^(\d+)\s+.*\n(\1)\@<!\d+\s` and `\v^(\d+)\s+.*\n\1\@!` (to my surprise `\v^(\d+)\s+.*\n\1\@=` does match lines 1, 2 and 4 so I don't get why using `\@!` gives the "inverse" of that).

***Edit:***
*Note the most important mistake was to use `\@` instead of just `@` since we are in very magic mode (`\v`). See accepted answer for full solution.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to get the right match:

```bash
\v^(\d+)\s.*\n\1@!\d@=
```

Which is equivalent of this PCRE regex:

```bash
^(\d+)\s.*\n(?!\1)(?=\d)
```

Here `(?=\d)` or `\d@=` is used to make sure to not to match last line in your input.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Beokx0/2)

Answer (score 0):

The "corrected" regex is `\v^(\d+)\s.*\n\1@!`. *(Edit: See @anubhava's answer to also avoid matching the last line.)*

##### Explanation

The answer is a bit ridiculous but I keep the question in case someone else makes the same mistake...

Very magic `\v` also affects `@` so no backslash is needed. Including it (as I did) escapes `@` into an ordinary character.

Comment: As @anubhava shows, you need `\d@=` at the end to avoid matching the last line.